# Flipping vertical data into horizontal with extracting specific information in R

Tags: r, reshape2

I have seen some nice explanation about how to flip data from horizontal to vertical. However, I need a bit of different organisation after change the columns into rows.

Here is my data:

```
Compound    Frequency   Type
C1  -0.853272929    A
C2  -0.780699577    A
C3  -0.614477598    A
C4  -0.130738078    A
C5  0.142499411 A
C6  0.148570388 A
C7  0.108864569 A
C8  1.036668305 A
C9  0.057404313 A
C10 -0.024941378    A
C1  0.003007008 B
C2  0.104085077 B
C3  0.051143686 B
C4  -1.060236186    B
C5  -0.484587066    B
C6  -0.15934591 B
C7  0.189355481 B
C8  -0.037796111    B
C9  0.522518879 B
C10 -0.184031867    B
C1  0.148570388 C
C2  0.108864569 C
C3  1.036668305 C
C4  0.057404313 C
C5  -0.024941378    C
C6  0.003007008 C
C7  0.104085077 C
C8  0.051143686 C
C9  -1.060236186    C
C10 -0.484587066    C
C1  -0.011113991    D
C2  4.196813014 D
C3  0.133978213 D
C4  -0.252406687    D
C5  0.517614284 D
C6  0.087048873 D
C7  3.316242168 D
C8  4.331790602 D
C9  -0.464324736    D
C10 0.107550844 D
```

I'd like to transform into this version:

```
    C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  C10
A   -0.853272929    -0.780699577    -0.614477598    -0.130738078    0.142499411 0.148570388 0.108864569 1.036668305 0.057404313 -0.024941378
B   0.003007008 0.104085077 0.051143686 -1.060236186    -0.484587066    -0.15934591 0.189355481 -0.037796111    0.522518879 -0.184031867
C   0.148570388 0.108864569 1.036668305 0.057404313 -0.024941378    0.003007008 0.104085077 0.051143686 -1.060236186    -0.484587066
D   -0.011113991    4.196813014 0.133978213 -0.252406687    0.517614284 0.087048873 3.316242168 4.331790602 -0.464324736    0.107550844
```

As you can see, header part disappeared. I'd like to keep in each row one type and as new header compounds. This was a simple version of 10 compounds. I have 400 of them and would like to do this type of data transformation.

I'll be happy if you can help me on this. Thank you very much.

Kindest regards,

Bahti

Comment: Try `library(reshape2); dcast(df, Type ~ Compound, value.var="Frequency")` (where I've assumed your data frame is called `df`).

Comment: Did you try something that didn't work?  If so, please add your code to the question.  This looks like a straightforward job for `dcast` based on your reshape2 tag.

Comment: No I didn't try actually. I just saw it in another question and tried that one. But it was not the one I want. Thanks a lot for your help. I'll check dcast now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tidyr` package

```
library(tidyr)
data_wide <- spread(data, Compound, Frequency)
data_wide

Type           C1         C10         C2          C3          C4          C5           C6        C7          C8
1    A -0.853272929 -0.02494138 -0.7806996 -0.61447760 -0.13073808  0.14249941  0.148570388 0.1088646  1.03666831
2    B  0.003007008 -0.18403187  0.1040851  0.05114369 -1.06023619 -0.48458707 -0.159345910 0.1893555 -0.03779611
3    C  0.148570388 -0.48458707  0.1088646  1.03666831  0.05740431 -0.02494138  0.003007008 0.1040851  0.05114369
4    D -0.011113991  0.10755084  4.1968130  0.13397821 -0.25240669  0.51761428  0.087048873 3.3162422  4.33179060
       C9
1  0.05740431
2  0.52251888
3 -1.06023619
4 -0.46432474
```

Comment: Thanks a lot "thecatalyst". It worked amazingly. Cheers!